# Is it possible to work long hours in France?

Tags: hours, france

I do like, have liked in the past, to work long hours occasionally -- as a software developer, but maybe anyone who enjoys their work or maybe learning something may relate.

> [hacking run](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacking-run.html): n.
> [analogy with ‘bombing run’ or ‘speed run’] A hack session extended long outside normal working times, especially one longer than 12 hours. May cause you to change phase the hard way (see phase).

> [wizard](http://catb.org/jargon/html/W/wizard.html): n.
>
> 1. Transitively, a person who knows how a complex piece of software or hardware works (that is, who groks it); esp. someone who can find and fix bugs quickly in an emergency. Someone is a hacker if he or she has general hacking ability, but is a wizard with respect to something only if he or she has specific detailed knowledge of that thing. **A good hacker could become a wizard for something given the time to study it**.

Of course not everybody does and it shouldn't be forced on you, but I've enjoyed it sometimes and I found it's more-or-less normal, with startups, **occasionally** in North America.

But it France it seems illegal -- i.e. if you do then you could complain to the authorities, and your employer gets in trouble (maybe with the union too); and so the employer prohibits it officially, saying they want you not to -- they seem to mean it too, officially, unofficially, and on a personal level.

I can work normally 9-to-6 (with that 2-hour lunch break); and I like it that we are not over-worked. The boss says, "this is a marathon not a sprint".

But I find it strange, even restrictive, that this mode of work -- a few 14-hours days occasionally to produce something -- is missing, not even once a year.

Is it true that nobody works like this in France? Maybe feels like writing an extra something over a week-end?

If they do, how do they square that their employer? Or is it, "do it but don't tell anyone", or "do secretly it even when they officially tell you not to"?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97449/is-it-illegal-to-voluntarily-work-longer-than-the-law-allows

Comment: You seem to toggle between asking if doing so is a good idea in general, if others commonly do it, if it can be allowed even when your company says they don't want you to do it, or if it's legal to do so in France. Pick a lane.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @Flater -- "if doing so is a good idea" is emphatically not what I want to ask, so what should I add/edit/delete in the question to avoid asking that? Also I'm not asking about my company of course -- but I may be asking you about yours if you're in France.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- [europe](/questions/tagged/europe) (more specifically, the European Union): *legal*, assuming enough breaks, rest periods, and happens only occasionally
- [france](/questions/tagged/france): my *guess* is illegal, but I can't back it up
- [germany](/questions/tagged/germany): *illegal*, barring special and unusual circumstances

Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV. I *did* have some law classes in university, including classes on employment law. However, as our professors routinely pointed out, their goal was not to make us into lawyers, but instead enable us to recognize situations where we need to hire one, and *this would definitely be one of those situations*.

## [europe](/questions/tagged/europe)

While I don't know specifically about France, I know a little bit about the [*EU Working Time Directive*](https://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=706&intPageId=205). Since France is a Member State of the European Union, the EU Working Time Directive applies to France as well.

Note that, being a Directive and not a Regulation, the Directive has to be implemented into French Law. The EU gives broad leeway regarding the implementation of Directives into national Law, but the *outcomes* must be preserved. In other words, the *mechanics* in French Law could be different, and French Law could have *better* protections and *higher* penalties than prescribed by the Directive, but not *lower*.

Which means that even without knowing about French Law, the Directive at least gives a lower baseline.

The Working Time Directive guarantees the following protections for workers:

- A maximum *average* working time of 48 hours within a 7 day period.

  - It is left up to the member states whether this average is calculated across 4, 6, or 12 months.
- A rest break *during working time* after at most 6 hours.
- A minimum uninterrupted rest period of 11 consecutive hours within a 24 hour period.
- A minimum uninterrupted rest period of 24 consecutive hours within a 7 day period, *in addition to* the 11 hour daily rest.
- At least 4 weeks of paid annual leave.
- Extra protection for night work.

Note that the EU Working Time Directive also gives Member States the option to opt-out of certain protections:

- The rules on maximum weekly working time, minimum daily rest, breaks, minimum weekly rest and the length of night work may be softened for a specific category of workers or for a specific sector. (E.g., hospital workers.)
- Member States *may* allow individual employees to opt-out from the maximum weekly working hours. However, there are strict restrictions on this opt-out. In particular, the consent must be freely given, entirely voluntary, and there can be no detriment to the employee if they decide to not consent or withdraw their consent.

So, based *purely* on the EU Working Time Directive, an *occasional* 14-hour hacking run *would* be legal, provided that you take at least two rest breaks (to comply with "at most 6 hours without rest"), this happens only once a week on average (to comply with the maximum average working time), and you start late the next day (to comply with the 11 hour rest period).

## [france](/questions/tagged/france)

*However*, given all I know about employee protection in France, I highly doubt that France only adopted the absolute minimum of protections from the EU Working Time Directive.

I don't know whether France implemented either of the two "opt-outs". I would assume they implemented the first one, since it just makes sense for certain sectors, e.g., hospitals or the event / live music industry. However, even if France implemented this option, I highly doubt software engineering would be among the sectors which are exempt.

Given what I know about employee protection in France, the second one would be implemented with heavy restrictions and safeguards.

## [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

First, we need some definitions:

- *Werktag* ("legal workday") is any day except Sunday and public holidays. This means Saturday is a legal workday, which sometimes trips people up. It is generally illegal to work on a day that is not a *Werktag*.
- *Arbeitstag* ("customary workday") is any *Werktag* on which work is customarily performed in your company / sector. Which days are *Arbeitstage* can be defined individually in your contract, collectively in a *Betriebsvereinbarung* for an entire company or a collective bargaining agreement for an entire sector, or simply by custom. I.e., if everybody in the company just works from Monday to Friday, then *by custom*, Saturday is not an *Arbeitstag* despite being a *Werktag*. Most companies in Germany work only 5-day weeks from Monday to Friday.
- *Arbeitstag* can also refer to the *one specific day of work*, specifically, when it comes to the *beginning* and *end* of an *Arbeitstag*, i.e., when was the *earliest time that you started working* and the *latest time that you stopped working*, including all breaks.

Unfortunately, both *Werktag* and *Arbeitstag* translate to *workday* in English.

The rules for Germany are as follows:

- You can only work on *Werktage*, i.e., Monday to Saturday, excluding Sundays and public holidays. ([§9 ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__9.html))
- You cannot work more than 8 hours per *Werktag* on *average* during a 12 month or 24 week period. ([§3 ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__3.html))
- You cannot work more than 10 hours *total* on a single *Arbeitstag*, period. (§3 ArbZG)
- You cannot work more than 6 hours without taking a break. For working time between 6–9 hours, there must be at least 30 minutes of breaks, for more than 9 hours at least 45 minutes, in chunks no smaller than 15 minutes each. ([§4 ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__4.html))
- There must be a rest period of at least 11 hours between the end of one *Arbeitstag* and the beginning of the next. ([§5 ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__5.html))

So, in Germany, a 14 hour hacking run would be illegal because of the 10 hour limitation.

Note: there are various exceptions, but I can't see how any of them apply. For example, there is an exception when the working time includes a significant amount of on-call time where you are not actively working. Also, the rules don't apply to Higher Management (*Leitende Angestellte*), which are (broadly) defined as employees that can take decisions on behalf of the company without having to ask for permission or approval.

It is possible to "bend" some of the rules in a *Tarifvertrag* or in a *Betriebsvereinbarung* which is based in a *Tarifvertrag*. However, software engineers are typically not organized in a *Gewerkschaft* (trade union) and thus can't take part in collective bargaining agreements.

It is possible, though, that software engineers working in a company that is not primarily a software company might be covered. For example, software engineers working for a company manufacturing heavy machinery would probably be covered by the *Tarifvertrag* for metal workers.

## Don't ask, don't tell?

> If they do, how do they square that their employer? Or is it, "do it but don't tell anyone", or "do secretly it even when they officially tell you not to"?

According to a 2019 ruling by the Court of Justice of the EU, that would be illegal. According to this ruling, Member States *must* implement measures that require employers to keep objective, reliable, and accessible daily working time records of *all working time*. Previously, it was only required to record overtime, but not regular working hours.

Furthermore, courts have more and more adopted the stance that *ignorance is not an excuse*, given modern time tracking and recording tools. In other words, while in the past "I didn't realize my employees were working overtime" might have been a valid defense, and in the worst case, a may have resulted in a court order to implement better time tracking, nowadays the courts are moving towards a viewpoint that managers *must* know how much their employees are working, and if they don't, then that is, at best, negligent.

So, assuming it is illegal in the first place, then it doesn't matter. Even if you do it completely in secret without your boss knowing about it, or asking you to, the employer can *still* be punished because they *should have known* that you worked more than legally allowed and they should have prevented you from doing it.

## A peculiarity of working time law

A peculiarity of working time laws is that *only the employer can violate them*. So, it doesn't matter whether you were ordered to work late or you voluntarily chose to work late without having been asked to. In either case, it is illegal, and in either case, the employer can be punished.

Comment: Note: on other stacks, it is allowed to answer questions asking about a specific cultural / legal / geographical context with a different context, which is what I chose to do here (Germany vs. France). I could not find any guidance about this on Meta. There does not seem to be a specific rule against it.

Comment: Thank you. If anything other than the official answer is literally illegal then this (the official answer) may be the only answer -- except from anyone with personal experience to the contrary (which is why I asked). Re. the "second opt-out" there may be a "union" to consider too, i.e. the union might not like individuals doing it. When I worked for startups in North America I was never "unionized"..

Comment: Additional note for Germany, the Arbeitstage don't have to match up with calendar days so you can't get around the regulation by working overnight. If you start working at 8 pm then by 6 am the next morning you have reached the maximum 10 hours for a work day. Then the 11 hours of rest would start running. You could then start you next Arbeitstag in the evening of that day.

Comment: Are we sure that the laws make working these long hours illegal, or just that the laws make it illegal for employers to require long hours? What would be the situation if the employee decided to work long hours entirely of their own volition, with the employer's knowledge (for appropriate record keeping) and with the employee prepared to stand up in court and state that they did the extra hours entirely for their own purposes and sear under oath that the employer did not ask them to?

Comment: @DJClayworth: It doesn't matter. The law is very clear and makes no exemptions: [§22,I (1) and (5) ArbZG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__22.html) state that the employer commits a misdemeanor offense whenever they "beschäftigen" (roughly "employ") an employee for longer than what is allowed in §3 and on days other than what is allowed in §9,I, respectively. It doesn't matter whether the employee agreed or not. **IFF** this is specified in a *Tarifvertrag* and **IFF** the employee freely consents, then, and only then can the maximum working time extended beyond 8/10 hours *but only*

Comment: … *if that time includes significant portions of on-call readiness*. The consent must be given in writing, and must be securely recorded. Consent can be withdrawn within 6 months for any reason or no reason at all. There can be no negative consequences for refusing or withdrawing consent.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Even that could probably be abused by employers whose employees do not have many alternatives (eg in supermarkets) or by types like Elon Musk.

Comment: You can't go shopping or to a restaurant on Sunday in Germany? Huh.

Comment: @nick012000: As I explained in my answer, there are exceptions, but they almost certainly do not apply to the OP's situation and are thus irrelevant to my answer to the OP's question. Of course, some – but definitely not all– restaurants are open on Sundays. Shops, though, are usually closed on Sundays. There are special days designated by the municipality called "verkaufsoffener Sonntag" where you can go shopping on Sundays. My city just increased the number of such Sundays from 4 to 5 per year.

Answer (score 2):

Working in France.

It will all depend on your company.
Some will be quite strict about your working hours.
Some others (including many startups) will allow you to do you working hours whenever you like in the week, as long as you get the job done and get at least the required number of hours in the week (usually you work a bit more than this, but if some day you want to quit at 3pm, nobody will complain in exchange).

In both companies (robotics startups) I worked for, when there was a deadline for which we where late, it was expected to stay late (usually, when staying after diner time, the boss would order some pizzas). In the first one (low on budget), we would usually just work easy for a few days after the rush ended. On the current one, if the rush is prolonged, there is usually some bonus.

At my current company, there is no fixed time for the end of day, but usually we end around 6-6:30 pm. But if we are fully into some task, it's common to continue until 7-7:30 pm. Later isn't usual, but still happens from time to time when there is something urgent to finish. The record was one week ending in average at 10pm, with one night ending at 1am.

So if you work in small startups, it's likely nobody will complain if you do a hacking run. If there is a deadline, it might even be expected (but I guess it will be dangerous for the employer to impose it above some limits).

For bigger companies, it might be less appreciated (but I haven't any real experiences in those).

If you care, best ask the company you want to join.